# MongoDB Convert String to Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, type-conversion

I'm very new to MongoDB and experience some difficulties in importing data into the database. Now I have a collection of documents which looks like

```
db.Question.findOne()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("124"),
"Answers" : "[\"502\",\"784\",\"1060\"]",
}
```

The Answers are now stored as a single string. However I want to convert it to a list like below so I could unwind it when doing query.

```
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("124"),
    "Answers" : ["502","784","1060"],
    }
```

Any idea how to do it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use JSON.parse() to change string type to list and then save the collection with update element. Below is a example:

```
db.Question.find({}).snapshot().forEach(function (el){el.Answers=JSON.parse(el.Answers);db.Question.save(el)});
```

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to apply `JSON.parse` to each of these strings:

```
> JSON.parse("[\"502\",\"784\",\"1060\"]")
[ '502', '784', '1060' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

First remove "[" and "]" in the data, then use below code, which create a new attribute,answers, which is a array/list that holds individual numbers:

```
db.Question.find({}).snapshot().forEach(function (el) {
    el.answers=el.Answers.substring(1,el.Answers.length-1);     
    el.answers = el.Answers.split(',');  
         db.Question.save(el); 
});
```

Comment: No need to remove the brackets literals, use `JSON.parse` on the current `Answers` value as suggested by @RayToal below `db.Question.find({}).snapshot().forEach(function (el) {
    el.Answers = JSON.parse(el.Answers);  
    db.Question.save(el); 
});`